# How can I run a scheduling process incrementally?

Tags: optaplanner

I ideally want to run a scheduling but this needs to be run incrementally.

Scheduling:
Given a set of resource R1,R2...Rn we ideally want to choose a Resource based on a set of constraints and assign it to a Entity for a given period of time in a day. Once a resource is assigned for a given time period, we cannot use that particular resource in the same time. Does this look similar to Meeting scheduling?

Scheduling process, Something like, say,

1. At the beginning of time, no resources are allotted to any entities.
2. When a request comes from a particular entity for a resource, we send a request JSON response and find a resource for a given time period that fits the criteria and returns a JSON response.
3. As more requests come in, we maintain the existing state of resource-entity but the newer requests will be solved. So the current state might need to be stored and needs to be given for future requests.

How can I do this with JSON requests/response.

Is there any example I can use for reference.

The attached diagram shows that this might be possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the user guide, take a look at **Continuous Planning** and **Real-time planning** (including **daemon mode**).

Note that if you may only assign *one resource at a time* and you can't reassign existing resources, then it's not NP-hard. This means you can't do any big cost savings and there's no need to use OptaPlanner (Drools for example suffices).